# sqlite3 integrity_check passed by jdbc says database image is malformed

Tags: scala, jdbc, sqlite, slick

I have a 16Gb sqlite3 database that is throwing this error when I can it via jdbc:

```
[SQLException: [SQLITE_CORRUPT]  The database disk image is malformed (database disk image is malformed)]

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[SQLException: [SQLITE_CORRUPT]  The database disk image is malformed (database disk image is malformed)]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:293)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:220)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_CORRUPT]  The database disk image is malformed (database disk image is malformed)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387)
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:374)
    at org.sqlite.NestedDB.prepare(NestedDB.java:134)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:123)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:42)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:404)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:399)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:383)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:252)
```

I checked the database with the sqlite3 command-line utility and there is no issue:

```
sqlite> pragma integrity_check;
ok
sqlite>
```

I can query it fine with the sqlite3 command-line utility but not with jdbc because of the exception.

I have 8 other databases (all created the same way using csv loader in the command-line utility) that are ~1Gb each and there is no issue accessing them with jdbc (called by slick)..

I tried dumping the database with

```
echo '.dump' | sqlite3 titleRelV4.db | sqlite3 titleRelV4_COPY.db
```

but that did not help at all.. I am confused.. Is 16Gb too large for a sqlite database?  Is there anything else I can do?

**Edit.**
The database is working on linux.  Looks like a mac specific bug.

Comment: It sounds like the same issue discussed in the sqlite-jdbc issue tracker [here](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/30/nestedvm-driver-incorrectly-claims-a-large).

Comment: That looks like the same issue, it looks like the database works on linux but not mac.  I am using slick which is a DB abstraction layer so I am not sure how to turn off isNativeMode though

Answer (score 0):

I closed sqlitestudio when I was running the java application that used the sqlite database that had the problem and I no longer had any error messages. The cause of all I think is that the database no longer accepts connections or fails to manage them, so if there are multiple simultaneous access you have in java the exception "disk image is malformed (code 11)"